# StateMachines and colour changes

Tags: mdriven

If my state machine goes to "Agreement" i want the state to be green everywhere, if it goes to "Rejection" i want it to go red everywhere. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is a property on your object - you show that property in a view - when you show it also add an style-expression - and reference a style defined with StylesInModel.
One efficient way is declare style names like: Contract_Agreement and Contract_Rejection, make them green and red.
Then set the style-expression to 'Contract_'+self.State , this way when the state changes the style does to.